# How to store url parameter and use it to redirect after login in Laravel (with Inertia & Vue)?

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I have an oauth website in Laravel using Jetstream with Inertia and Vue. => **Website A**.
It is used for authentication, user management and access tokens.
This website is used as a SSO and grants access to different websites (on different domains).

I have another website (**Website B**) that uses **Website A** for the authentication.
A user trying to log in on **Website B** is redirected to the **Website A** `www.websitea.com/login?origin=websiteb`.
I can send the origin as a url parameter. How can I store it and use it to redirect the user back to **Website B** once logged in ?

Thanks to [Matheus Dal'Pizzol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4075162/matheus-dalpizzol)'s answer I know how to redirect the user to the url with Inertia.

I am familiar with Laravel but I am lost with this Inertia and Vue setup...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the whole process, but Inertia offers a way to redirect from Laravel to an external url:

```php
return Inertia::location($url);
```

Comment: Thanks that's great and that's one step of the process. I have two different websites that will both use my oauth website to register, login, reset passwords... The users will have one profile to use both websites. If a user wants to log in on website A, once authenticated he/she should be redirected to website A.

Comment: I need to know, when a user is on the oauth website, where he/she comes from. From website A ? website B ? or if the oauth website has been accessed directly. I could set the origin as a url parameter, store it in a cookie and use that to make the correct redirection. But I am completely lost in that Laravel oauth website and I don't how to do so. Dunno if it is the way to go either...